# ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df as follows:

```
EscRF_P2P_Volt_V    ContextID   StepID  Time_Elapsed    iso_forest
12.4542121887207    7289972 15  32.472  1
27.1062278747559    7289972 15  33.444  1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  37.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  38.513000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  39.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  40.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  41.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  42.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  43.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  44.503  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  45.532000000000004  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  46.502  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  47.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  48.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  49.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  50.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  51.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  52.501000000000005  -1
622.710632324219    7289972 19  53.502  -1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  102.49000000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  104.078 1
22.7106227874756    7289973 24  104.92800000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  105.81800000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  106.918 1
22.7106227874756    7289973 24  107.61000000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  108.65  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  108.73100000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  109.19800000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  110.12  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  111.11000000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  112.108 1
22.7106227874756    7289973 24  113.11000000000001  1
21.97802162170409   7289973 24  114.11000000000001  -1
22.7106227874756    7289973 24  115.11000000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  116.11000000000001  1
22.7106227874756    7289973 24  117.18  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  118.13000000000001  1
23.4432239532471    7289973 24  119.13000000000001  1
```

The `ContextID` is a product and I have 1400 different ContextIDs meaning that I have 1400 different products. I am trying to overlap and plot 200 different ContextIDs at once in one window, the next 200 in the second window and so on. In the end, I get 7 windows for 1400 products. For achieving the same, I wrote the following code:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue = None):
    #Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks
    #grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def add_to_axes(ax, data, param, context_id = None):
    data.plot(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, label = context_id, ax = ax)
    outlier = data["iso_forest"] == -1
    data[~outlier].plot.scatter(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, color = "green", ax = ax)
    data[outlier].plot.scatter(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, color = "red", ax = ax)

def group_plots(df, param, group_size = 200):
    for group in grouper(df.groupby("ContextID"), n = group_size):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        for context_id, data in filter(None, group):
            add_to_axes(ax, data, param, context_id)
            ax.legend().set_visible(False)
        yield fig
```

and when I do

```
Epvv['plot_data'] = Epvv['merged_df']
for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(Epvv['plot_data'], 'EscRF_P2P_Volt_V')):
    show()
```

for the above df, it gives me the following error:

```
    for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(Epvv['plot_data'], 'EscRF_P2P_Volt_V')):
    show()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-cdcfbb39cc21>", line 1, in <module>
    for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(Epvv['plot_data'], 'EscRF_P2P_Volt_V')):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b8732ccafe84>", line 46, in group_plots
    add_to_axes(ax, data, param, context_id)

  File "<ipython-input-1-b8732ccafe84>", line 39, in add_to_axes
    data[outlier].plot.scatter(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, color = "red", ax = ax)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 3516, in scatter
    return self(kind='scatter', x=x, y=y, c=c, s=s, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2942, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1973, in plot_frame
    **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1740, in _plot
    kind=kind, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 860, in __init__
    super(ScatterPlot, self).__init__(data, x, y, s=s, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 804, in __init__
    raise ValueError(self._kind + ' requires x column to be numeric')

ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric
```

But, when I apply the same to a second df

```
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  ContextID   StepID  Time_Elapsed    iso_forest
1.953125    7289972 1   0.0 1
1.953125    7289972 1   0.055   1
2.05078125  7289972 2   0.156   -1
2.05078125  7289972 2   0.48700000000000004 -1
2.05078125  7289972 2   1.477   -1
1.953125    7289972 2   2.4770000000000003  1
1.7578125   7289972 2   3.4770000000000003  1
1.7578125   7289972 2   4.487   1
1.85546875  7289972 2   5.993   1
1.7578125   7289972 2   6.545000000000001   1
9.08203125  7289972 5   7.9830000000000005  -1
46.6796875  7289972 5   13.093  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   13.384  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   14.388000000000002  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   15.386000000000001  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   16.386000000000003  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   17.396  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   18.406000000000002  1
46.6796875  7289972 5   19.396  1
74.12109375 7289973 19  98.89800000000001   1
74.12109375 7289973 19  99.59800000000001   1
74.12109375 7289973 19  100.488 1
74.90234375 7289973 19  101.798 1
6.4453125   7289973 24  102.49000000000001  -1
3.515625    7289973 24  104.078 -1
2.5390625   7289973 24  104.92800000000001  -1
2.05078125  7289973 24  105.81800000000001  1
2.05078125  7289973 24  106.918 1
2.05078125  7289973 24  107.61000000000001  1
1.953125    7289973 24  108.65  1
```

and do

```
Bgf['plot_data'] = Bgf['merged_df']
for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(Bgf['plot_data'], 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm')):
    show()
```

it works perfectly fine without any errors an gives me 7 different windows, each having a time plot of 200 different products.

I also checked the datatype of both the dataframes and they were the same:

```
print(Bgf['plot_data'].dtypes)
BacksGas_Flow_sccm    float64
ContextID              object
StepID                 object
Time_Elapsed          float64
iso_forest             object
dtype: object

print(Epvv['plot_data'].dtypes)
EscRF_P2P_Volt_V    float64
ContextID            object
StepID               object
Time_Elapsed        float64
iso_forest           object
dtype: object
```

I don't understand what is the mistake I am doing here, since the code is working for one df and not working for the other. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are we supposed to run your code? This line `Epvv['plot_data'] = Epvv['merged_df']` and `for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(Epvv['plot_data'], 'EscRF_P2P_Volt_V')):     show()` doesn't work. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
`

Comment: I have a dictionary named `Epvv` and `plot_data` & `merged_df` are the dataframes in it. I guess you can try removing the dictionary name

Comment: `plot_data = merged_df` and `for i, fig in enumerate(group_plots(plot_data, EscRF_P2P_Volt_V)): show()`

Comment: Your code is working fine for me for the first dataframe. What matplotlib version are you using. Find it using `import matplotlib` and then `print (matplotlib.__version__)`

Comment: @Sheldore 3.0.3

Comment: Try the two workaround solutions answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out the following alternative using `matplotlib`'s `scatter` plot. There seems to be a related [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18755)

```
def add_to_axes(ax, data, param, context_id = None):
    data.plot(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, label = context_id, ax = ax)
    outlier = data["iso_forest"] == -1
    xvals = data[~outlier]["Time_Elapsed"].values
    yvals = data[~outlier][param].values
    ax.scatter(xvals, yvals, color = "green",)

    xvals = data[outlier]["Time_Elapsed"].values
    yvals = data[outlier][param].values
    ax.scatter(xvals, yvals, color = "red")
```

[image: work]

**Alternatively**, you can skip the `scatter` plot and just try using `plot` with a marker

```
def add_to_axes(ax, data, param, context_id = None):
    data.plot(x = "Time_Elapsed", y = param, label = context_id, ax = ax)
    outlier = data["iso_forest"] == -1
    data[~outlier].plot("Time_Elapsed",param, style=".", color='green', ax=ax)
    data[outlier].plot("Time_Elapsed",param, style=".", color='red', ax=ax)
```